# Rails - order by joint attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I just upgraded my project to rails 4 and i'm getting an error on this line :

```
Group.first.event_joins.order(event: [:threshold]).reverse
```

This line should select the event_joins and order them by threshold. The threshold column is in the event table not in the event_joins table. I would like to like to order the event_joins by event treshold. How can I write this in rails 4 ?

The error  :

```
ArgumentError: Direction "[:threshold]" is invalid. Valid directions are: [:asc, :desc, :ASC, :DESC, "asc", "desc", "ASC", "DESC"]
```

Thanks

Comment: Try `Group.first.event_joins.order('events.threshold desc')` if you want in descending order or just `Group.first.event_joins.order('events.threshold')` if you want in ascending order.

Comment: I'm getting a sql error : Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'events.threshold' in 'order clause'

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
Group.first.event_joins.order('events.threshold').reverse
```

Rails 4 supports hash arguments, eg `order(model: :asc)` but i have no idea how to make it work through associations.

Comment: i'm getting a SQL error : 

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'event.threshold' in 'order clause': SELECT `event_joins`.* FROM `event_joins` WHERE `event_joins`.`eventable_id` = 1 AND `event_joins`.`eventable_type` = 'Group'  ORDER BY event.threshold

Comment: Please add your model associations to the question. I assumed it was a simple `belongs_to` event, but doesn't look like it now.

Answer (score 0):

The event_join belongs to an event.

This worked out for me :

```
group.event_joins.joins(:event).order("events.threshold").reverse
```

cheers